# A very simple look on limits

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

Could we define limits of functions like this?

A function f(x) has no value in x0 because the denominator at x0 is 0. By applying limit we determine a fictive value for x0 which the function tends to have from both sides but can not . In order to do this we eliminate factors that make it impossible to calculate f(x0); meaning they make the denominator 0.

I know it's not simple as that but I wonder could this be the starting point for studying limits? It's first year college math course btw.

Thanks in advance

Comment: An example to explain what you are thinking helps readers understand better.

Comment: This definition is definitely *not* precise enough to use as the basis for a mathematical theory.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, I think this is a fine way to calculate limits.  For example,

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$$

And we want to take the limit $x\to1$:

$$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=\frac{\require{cancel}\cancel{(x-1)}(x+1)}{\cancel{x-1}}=x+1$$

So that we have

$$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to1}x+1=1+1=2$$

This is often seen as the 'algebraic' way to evaluating a limit, and the key is to remove whatever is keeping us from calculating the limit.

Comment: Thanks all I needed was a starting point to see what exactly I was dealing with.

Comment: @Onthespot No problem.  ;)